# Can get cheerio to extract tag

Tags: javascript, cheerio

```
    wp = $('.badge-success').text();
```

the code i currently have.

I am trying get the text value "(6)" of the underlined tag in the image to an variable. 
[the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Edyy.png)
There is another tag with the exact same classes but it is not as nested. I can get it to select that one but not the one i want.

How can I select the right one?

Comment: "_There is another tag with the exact same classes_" can you please share the image for that also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the id in the parent element. There can only be one id.

```
wp = $('#T2_METALBAR').find('.badge-success').text();
```

I sort of abbreviated your code and it works. Notice that I have two divs with the class 'badge-success' and it only pulls the correct one. Maybe this will help you see where your code or html is different:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const html = "<div class='badge-success'>unwanted text<div class='card-box'>text<p id='T2_METALBAR'>text<span class='badge-success'>6--text I want</span><p></div></div>"
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const res = $('#T2_METALBAR').find('.badge-success').text();
console.log(res); // logs '6--text I want'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the id in the parent element. There can only be one id.

```
wp = $('#T2_METALBAR').find('.badge-success').text();
```

Comment: for some reason this only returns a value of undefined